# Output is "from parent". Not getting how ? when not passing the arguments in any constructor the output is "from neighbour"

Tags: java

```
class Parent {
void Child(Parent p){
    System.out.println("from parent");
}}
```

> passing arguments in the constructors

```
class Uncle extends Parent{
void Child(Uncle u){
    System.out.println("from uncle");
}}
```

> created class passed an argument

```
class Neighbour extends Uncle{
void Child(Neighbour n){
    System.out.println("from neighbour");
}}
```

> one more inherited class

```
public class TestIt {    
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Parent p=new Neighbour();
    Uncle n=new Neighbour();
    n.Child(p);
}}
```

output is "from parent"

> when not passing arguments the output is "from neighbour"

Comment: Welcome to SO. Could you clarify what you're confused about? At the end you specify two different things that print, however I'm not sure which case is for the code you provided

Comment: Also, you should check out the Java naming conventions linked at the end. Reading your code, many would see Child as a constructor, which can be confusing. http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconventions-135099.html

Answer (score 0):

From [java official documantation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/override.html)

"If a subclass defines a static method with the **same signature as a static method in the superclass**, then the method in the subclass hides the one in the superclass."

on the example you provided void Child(Uncle u) is best match for the call.
There is class detection only the object activating the method but not the parameter. when you call the object method recognized as Neighbour, but the parameteris recognized as Uncle .

null is a valid value for the types Object, that is why it choose "from neighbour", assuming that what you mean by "not passing arguments".